# can't set ckeditor toolbar location at bottom

Tags: editor, ckeditor, config

I'm trying [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/), but I can't set the toolbar location to the bottom (by default it is set to the top).
I read the documentation, and I wrote this snipet in config.js file:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
   config.toolbarLocation = 'bottom';
}
```

In config.js I have defined a toolbar and `config.toolbarLocation = 'bottom'` then I call ckeditor in this mode:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', { toolbar : 'Full'    });
```

Did I foget something else?  It doesn't work. I see only textarea without toolbar (the toolbar at the top disappears).
Can you help me, please?

Comment: That setting works fine for me, maybe you're doing something else wrong?

Comment: in config.js I have define a toolbar and config.toolbarLocation = 'bottom'; then I call ckeditor in this mode:  CKEDITOR.replace('editor', { 
           toolbar : 'Full'    
         }); Did I foget something else?

Comment: You might have a syntax error in the toolbar definition

Comment: I solved the problem. The problem was that I add this snipet: .cke_bottom {display: none;} for hide bottom status bar, but this code hide also ckeditor toolbar. For hide status bar at bottom I use this code in config.js file now: config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is priority to be covered. Try this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', { toolbar : 'Full', toolbarLocation : 'bottom' });
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ckeditor 4 they have option to move toolbar to bottom but not in Ckeditor 5.

Check configuration table [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/migrate.html#configuration-options-compatibility-table)

So, I did the CSS tweak.
Add a parent class to parent div of Ckeditor element and then add these:

**1. Using flex-direction to flip order of toolbar and editing area:**

```
 .ck.ck-reset.ck-editor {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
-moz-flex-direction: column-reverse;
-ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
flex-direction: column-reverse
    }
```

**2. Assign less height to Toolbar and more to edit area:**

```
.ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable {

        height: 200px;
    }

    .ck.ck-editor .ck-editor__top .ck-sticky-panel .ck-toolbar,
    .ck-sticky-panel__content {
        height: 54px;
    }
```

**2. Remove shadow and outline when focusing on edit area (optional, only if you want):**

```
.ck-focused, .ck.ck-editor__editable:not(.ck-editor__nested-editable).ck-focused {
        border: none;
        border: none;
outline: none !important;
-moz-outline: none !important;
-webkit-outline: none !important;
-ms-outline: none !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
                    /*
                     * Ensure that htmlwriter plugin, which is required for this sample, is loaded.
                     */
                    //                extraPlugins: 'htmlwriter',
                    toolbarLocation: 'bottom',
                    height: 200,
                    width: '100%',
                    toolbar: [
                        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink'],
                        ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
                        ['TextColor']
                    ]});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
.ck.ck-editor {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your code?

Comment: @MichaelM. this code is for set ckeditor toolbar location at bottom